# THREE.js flickering with pointlight and MeshFaceMaterial

Tags: three.js, textures, flicker, lighting

For some reason I am getting flicker on any objects with using MeshFaceMaterial while I have a pointlight in the scene. Ambient and Directional lights are fine.

This is unfortunate, the pointlight adds an extra level of realism to the scene. If I remove the pointlight all is well. Pseudo code:

```
light = new THERE.PointLight(0xffffff,0.5);
scene.add(light);

loadTerrain();

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cominedGeometry,new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray))
scene.add(mesh);
```

I've tried loading the light before and after all other objects have loaded, no change in the flickering.

Why is there flickering under these conditions?  Is there any remedy for this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is there flickering in the conitions described?